# Prevent a using-statement from happening

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to have a custom view mode, to show online user text and not online user some other text.

But I want to do it like the `Html.BeginForm()`, in a using statement.

I have made a class witch can write text at the start of the using and text, but I cant get it to stop the text in the {} from happening.

```html
@using (AuthorizedContent(Html, "Adminstrator"))
{
    <text>Only the administrator should see this</text>
}
```

with

```
public static Test AuthorizedContent(this HtmlHelper helper, String roleName)
{
    return null;
    var test = new Test(helper);
    return test;
}

public class Test : IDisposable
{
    private HtmlHelper _helper;

    public Test(HtmlHelper helper) {
        _helper = helper;
        this.StartTag();
    }

    public void StartTag()
    {
        var writer = _helper.ViewContext.Writer;
        writer.Write("Hello");
    }

    public void EndTag()
    {
        var writer = _helper.ViewContext.Writer;
        writer.Write("Hello");
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        this.EndTag();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it - just delete four lines, and they won't happen. What is the real goal?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the body of the using statement from rendering?  What is the point?

Comment: @KirkWoll: I'd guess that the OP wants to prevent the body of the using statement from rendering when the user is not an administrator.

Comment: I want to do it so I can specify a Role for my view..

Comment: The text in <text> means "Only the adminstor sould see this"

Comment: Could you check the user's rights in `StartTag()` and, if they are not an admin, put a token in.  Then, in `EndTag()` could check for that token and, if it exists, delete everything in the stream from the token on?  Doesn't seem like the most efficient thing, but it could do what you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prevent the body of the `using` from rendering in a Razor page. If you want to prevent something from rendering use an `if` condition:

```
@if (AuthorizedContent(Html, "Adminstrator"))
{
    <text>Only the administrator should see this</text>
}
```

or looking at the name of this method maybe you are trying to reinvent something that already exists:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Adminstrator"))
{
    <text>Only the administrator should see this</text>
}
```

Comment: Okey, what a downer.. Hehe.. :)

Then I just will use a if.. :)